# java error - how to solve the \n in the buffer (if that is the cause of the error)

Tags: java

The following is my code.
The code works fine with the 'save' and 'search' menus.
However, **after I 'delete' a person and select the next menu as 'search', the program skips the part where the user enters a name, thus showing "no results found" as the result.**

I thought that the \n may be the problem and **tried parseInt(), System.out.flush(), and using nextLine() as written in the comments in the code** but they all seemed not to work.

Also, **I am confused why in some cases, even though there is a \n left in the buffer, I can enter the 'name' without the program skipping.**

Please let me know if the \n is not the cause of the problem.
Thank you for your time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PhoneInfo
{
    String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String birthDay;
    private String birthYear;
    private int choice;

    public PhoneInfo(String name, String phoneNumber, String birthDay)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }

    public PhoneInfo(String name, String phoneNumber, String birthDay, String birthYear)
    {
        this(name, phoneNumber, birthDay);
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }

    public void showPhoneInfo()
    {
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
        System.out.println("phone no.: " + phoneNumber);
        System.out.println("birthday: " + birthDay);
        if(birthYear == null)
            System.out.println("birth year: no record");
        else
            System.out.println("birth year: " + birthYear);

        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    }
} 

class Manager //save, search, delete data
{
    PhoneInfo[] pBook = new PhoneInfo[100];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public PhoneInfo inputData()
    {   
        System.out.print("name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("phone no.: ");
        String phoneNumber = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("birthday: ");
        String birthDay = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("birth year: ");
        String birthYear = input.nextLine();

        PhoneInfo pData = new PhoneInfo(name, phoneNumber, birthDay, birthYear);

        System.out.println("-----------------------------");

        return pData;
    }

    public void saveData()
    {   
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            if(pBook[i] == null)
            {   
                pBook[i] = inputData(); //new entry
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if(i == 99)
                    System.out.println("database full");
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
    }

    public void searchData()
    {
        System.out.print("name: ");
        //tried putting System.out.flush(); here as well... didn't work
        String name = input.nextLine(); // do not want to use input.next() if possible
        System.out.println("\nSearching data...\n");
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            if(pBook[i] != null)
            {
                if(pBook[i].name.equals(name))
                {
                    pBook[i].showPhoneInfo();
                        break;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("no results found");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void deleteData()
    {
        int idx;
        System.out.print("name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();

        idx = getIndex(name);
        if(idx == -1)
            System.out.println("no matching name");

        System.out.println("Are you sure you want to delete " + name + "?");
        System.out.print("1. yes\n2. no\n> ");
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        if(choice == 1)
        {   
            for(int i=idx; i<99; i++)
                pBook[i] = pBook[i+1];
            System.out.println(name + " deleted...");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        }
        if(choice == 2)
            return;
    }

    public int getIndex(String name)
    {
        int index = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {   
            if(pBook[i] != null)        
                if(pBook[i].name.equals(name)) //error --> worked when I added if(pBook[i] != null). why?? what difference did it make?
                    index = i;
                else
                    continue;
            else
                continue;
        }
        return index;
    }
}

class PhoneBookVer3
{
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void showMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("[MENU]");
        System.out.println("choose...");
        System.out.println("1. save data");
        System.out.println("2. search data");
        System.out.println("3. delete data");
        System.out.println("4. exit program");
        System.out.print("> ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PhoneBookVer3 pb = new PhoneBookVer3();
        int choice;
        Manager mng = new Manager();
        while(true)
        {
            pb.showMenu();
            //choice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()); // why this doesn't work either..
            choice = input.nextInt();
            //input.nextLine(); //why this doensn't consume the \n???

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
                    mng.saveData();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
                    mng.searchData();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
                    mng.deleteData();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
                    System.out.println("end of program");
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RussianVodka Um, does this have to do with my question??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after use nextInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)

Comment: @Tom I've already seen that page and I was trying to solve this problem using what I've learned. Using exception handlers are further back in the book that I'm using. If you've read the bold text I wrote above, I tried the thing in the post you mentioned. But they all didn't work

Comment: You'e calling `input.nextInt();` in the delete method. Since there are no comments there, you haven't tried anything else there, right? Try to do so. At the end, this is still a duplicate of the mentioned question. You've just changes the wrong line.

Comment: To avoid problems like that, you could read words the decisions. For example like this: `if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) { /* user entered "yes" */ }`. [JavaDoc of #equalsIgnoreCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @Tom A way to not use numbers and not deal with \n. That is an interesting way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading `choice` using the `input.nextInt()`. When you do that `nextInt()` will only read the `integer` and the `newline` character you enter will be read by the next `nextLine()` so to prevent this you can add a dummy `input.nextLine()` after the `input.nextInt()`

#### Code

```
System.out.println("Are you sure you want to delete " + name + "?");
System.out.print("1. yes\n2. no\n> ");
int choice = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // to read the newline character
```

#### Alternate method

Another method is to read the choice using `nextLine()` itself and then convert the input to `int`.

```
int choice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method `public void deleteData()`, you need to do:

```
int choice = input.nextInt();   
input.nextLine();
```

The last `nextLine()` will consume the `\n` that `nexInt()` is leaving.

Maybe it will be better that you use `parseLine()` more often and convert `String` to `int` when necessary.

Comment: Is using parseLine() rather than input.nextLine() considered better programming?

Comment: @asdfqwer Well, what behaviour do you expect when `choice` it's not a number?. If it is not, you will have an exception.

Comment: @asdfqwer Moreover, the answer you accepted suggest as alternative to convert the input to int without consider that this may fail and throw an exception.

Comment: oh I didn't know that since I didn't learn exceptions yet and I am only using notepad and console to program. And as for the alternative answer, I don't quite understand yet but I think I will keep your suggestion in mind when learning exceptions. Thank you.